# apache spark streaming with kafka and hive integration

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Is there anyway to integrate apache spark structured streaming with apache hive and apache kafka in one application

after adding list using collectAsList and storing it into list. I got the below error.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issues.

Thanks in Advance.

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException;


public class DatasetKafka {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Java Spark Hive Example").master("yarn")
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hive/warehouse")
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate();
        Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.ERROR);
        Dataset<String> lines = spark
                  .readStream()
                  .format("kafka")
                  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                  .option("subscribe", "test")
                  .load().selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
                  .as(Encoders.STRING());
        List<String> line=lines.collectAsList();
        for(String li:line) {
            String values[]=li.split(",");
            String query="insert into table match values("+Integer.parseInt(
            values[0])+
            ","+values[1]+
            ","+Integer.parseInt(values[2])+
            ","+Integer.parseInt(values[3])+
            ","+Integer.parseInt(values[4])+
            ","+values[5]+
            ","+Integer.parseInt(values[6])+
            ","+values[7]+
            ","+Integer.parseInt(values[8])+
            ","+Integer.parseInt(values[9])+
            ","+Integer.parseInt(values[10])+
            ","+values[11]+
            ","+Integer.parseInt(values[12])+
            ","+Integer.parseInt(values[13])+
            ","+Integer.parseInt(values[14])+
            ","+Integer.parseInt(values[15])+
            ","+Integer.parseInt(values[16])+
            ","+values[17]+
            ","+values[18]+")";
            spark.sql(query);
        }

//      List<String> values=ll.collectAsList();
        Dataset<String> words=lines.map((MapFunction<String, String>)k->{
            return k;
        }, Encoders.STRING());
        Dataset<Row> wordCounts = words.flatMap(
                (FlatMapFunction<String, String>) x -> Arrays.asList(x.split(",")).iterator(),
                Encoders.STRING()).groupBy("value").count();
        StreamingQuery query = wordCounts.writeStream()
                  .outputMode("complete")
                  .format("console")
                  .start();
                try {
                    query.awaitTermination();
                } catch (StreamingQueryException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
kafka
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$UnsupportedOperationChecker$$throwError(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$$anonfun$checkForBatch$1.apply(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$$anonfun$checkForBatch$1.apply(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.checkForBatch(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertSupported(QueryExecution.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData(QueryExecution.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3360)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectAsList(Dataset.scala:2794)
    at com.ges.kafka.DatasetKafka.main(DatasetKafka.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Comment: Personally, I would suggest using Kafka Connect's HDFS + Hive integration and not having to write more code than a config file. But that's just me...

Comment: Also, Hive can read from Kafka directly now, if that's all you're trying to do - https://hortonworks.com/blog/introducing-hive-kafka-sql/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the libraries

- `spark-sql-kafka` to read data from Kafka, see [Spark Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) and
- `spark-llap` to write data to Hive, see https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/spark-llap/

Both libraries are available on Maven.

A simple example of a Spark Structured Stream application is shown below. Make sure to create the Hive table in advance.

```scala
  val ds = spark.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config.getString("broker.list"))
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", config.getString("security.protocol"))
    .option("subscribe", config.getString("kafka.topic.in"))
    .option("startingOffsets", config.getString("kafka.starting.offset"))
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
    .load()
    .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING) AS key", "CAST(value AS STRING)")


  val query = ds.writeStream
    .format(HiveWarehouseSession.STREAM_TO_STREAM)
    .option("database", "my_database")
    .option("table", "my_table")
    .option("metastoreUri", spark.conf.get("spark.datasource.hive.warehouse.metastoreUri"))
    .option("checkpointLocation", config.getString("spark.checkpoint.dir"))
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(config.getLong("spark.batchWindowSizeSecs").seconds))
    .start()

  query.awaitTermination()
```